# Double Equals (==) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've been writing some unit tests in TypeScript. The example QUnit test contains:

```
  ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
```

The `tsc` compiler claims that:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'

And exits with status `1` (although it does correctly produce the JS).

The spec says:

> The <, >, <=, >=, ==, !=, ===, and !== operators
>
> These operators require one operand type to be identical to or a subtype of the other operand type. The 
>   result is always of the Boolean primitive type.

So it looks like the warning / error is correct. Doesn't this rather defeat the point of the type coercing `==` operator though? Is there ever a valid use case for using `==` in TypeScript that *won't* produce this warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At least one probable scenario for `==` (i.e., with type coercion) in TypeScript is when one of the expected operands is of Any type:

> A type S is a subtype of a type T, and T is a supertype of S, if one
>   of the following is true: [...]
>
> **T is the Any type.**

Now you probably see the picture: any function that has an Any param can safely (well, more-o-less; all the common gotchas of `==` are still applied here) compare it with value of any set type with `==`.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some common TypeScript examples that are allowed by the compiler and make use of `==`.

```
var a: string = "A";
var b: Object = "A";

if (a == b) {
    alert("Example 1");
}

var c: any = "1";
var d: number = 1;

if (c == d) {
    alert("Example 2");
}

var e: any = "E";
var f: string = "E";

if (e == f) {
    alert("Example 3");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the points of TypeScript means that we write clearer JavaScript. Do something like 1 == "1" and it won't work unless you explicitly cast it or use ToString() / ParseInt() anyway depending on whether you're expecting to compare strings or numbers.

You can use Any so that variables behave as usual dynamic JavaScript variables but then you're losing sight of the point of TS which is to benefit from a strong typing / type inference system that helps us not fall foul of the many JavaScript gotchas that exist because of its automatic type coercion rules.